# Articles/Links on Asp.Net pipeline and internal request processing architecture

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, architecture

I am looking details on the internal working of asp.net architecture. The topics need to include the following:

1. Asp.Net Thread/Application Pools
2. HttpRuntime
3. HttpApplication - When and how it is
   set up
4. How HttpContext is set up
5. How objects can passed along the
   pipeline using
   HttpContext.Current.Items
6. Why does modification of static
   variables requires locks in ASP.NET
   (advanced)
7. IIS 7 Integration Mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article from msdn magazine ([Securely Implement Request Processing, Filtering, and Content Redirection with HTTP Pipelines in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188942.aspx))  describes many of the topics you listed.

Comment: +1 Good article. Had already gone through it. Share more such if you have :)

Comment: This link needs to be updated to point to the intended source of information

Answer (score 1):

I think article shared by Matthew is a good one. Here's another one that offers quite a bit insight - http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0511061

Answer (score 0):

With regards to IIS7 Integrated Pipeline and IIS in general, the [IIS7 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=9550&locale=en-us) is fairly essential reference material. It's written by the IIS team and includes contributions from [Mike Volodarsky](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/) (Programme Manager) and [Carlos Aguilar Mares](http://www.carlosag.net/aboutme.aspx) (Development Lead).

As a developer I have this book by my desk all the time.

The [IIS.NET website](http://www.iis.net/overview/ModularAndExtensibleWebServer) is a pretty good resource too.